# Regex or Substring to Match Filename With Extension

Tags: c#, string

I have a current situation where I can be given a filename with path that looks like:

```
C:\\Users\\testUser\\Documents\\testFile.txt.9043632d298f44ad88509c677a8249f8
```

or

```
C:\\Users\\testUser\\Documents\\testFile.txt.9043632d298f44ad88509c677a8249f8.enc
```

I need to be able to extract everything up until the end of the extension (can be any file extension, will always have guid string preceded by a . after the extension)

So an example output would be:

```
C:\\Users\\testUser\\Documents\\testFile.txt
C:\\Users\\testUser\\Documents\\testFile.pdf
C:\\Users\\testUser\\Documents\\testFile.jpeg
```

I have tried substrings but cannot seem to get the proper input (though I assume it is a simple task). I can never seem to get the proper result.

An example I tried was along the lines of:

```
filename.Substring(0,filename.Indexof('.', //what goes here??));
```

but keep getting stuck.

Any help would be lovely!

Comment: You might use: new Regex(@".*(?=\.[a-f\d]{32})").Match(yourstring) That matches up to the guid (not including the dot)

Comment: @PoulBak just tested and it works, if you put it as the answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: @PoulBak Doesn't this rely on the guid string always being 32 chars long with lowercase letters

Comment: I have changed the answer to use 'ignorecase' although is should not be necessary.

Comment: Just use `lastIndexOf` instead.

Comment: @Charleh: That won't work in the second example

Comment: You could just do a two pass check, not everything needs regex

Comment: Not everything, only when it makes sense, which it does here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use:

```
new Regex(@".*(?=\.[a-f\d]{32})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(yourString)
```

**Explanation**:

.+ match one or more of any char

`(?= )` look ahead, check if the following chars match, but don't include in match

`\.` match a dot

`[a-f\d]{32}` match any character `a-f` or `digit` exactly 32 times

`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` ignores the case